# JavaScript button not resizing on mobile correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a search bar in my HTML and I am trying to put a magnifying glass button at its end. It looks fine on desktop, but on mobile the button is taller than the search bar. Much thanks if you know how to get it to be the same height on every viewport.

```css
.autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
}

button[type=reset] {
  background-color: #34587F;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border-radius: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:40%; font-family: 'Fjalla One'">
  <input id="searchField" type="text" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH" />
  <button type="reset" id="submit" onclick="goTo();"><i class="bi bi-search"></i> 
       </button>
</div>
```

[Appearance on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR3XO.png)

[Appearance on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pjqx.png)

Comment: Just give your `autocomplete` `display: flex` and your `input` `width: 100%` that's all and if you are added some special padding for your input remove it or update the post and add it

Comment: @JS_INF that did the trick, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting the height of the `reset` to `height: 100%` for the parent `autocomplete` div. Make sure that you're also setting the height of the `input`/`searchField` to the same height (i.e. `100%`) to match that of the `reset` button. If they're styled the same, make sure you set a height for the `autocomplete` class. Having an unset height for an absolutely positioned parent, with relative height children, may be causing your issues.

Comment: Is something like this:

input {

      border: none;

      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 2%;

      font-size: 2vw;

      border-radius: 5%;

      height: 100%;

   }

what you're referring to?

Comment: Try setting a height to the `autocomplete` class. Having an unset height for an absolutely positioned parent may be causing your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding a height to the autocomplete class made the height stay the same, but the button now repositions itself above the search bar on mobile devices. [picture](https://imgur.com/dOZSZOQ)

Comment: Alright! I would recommend trying `display: flex` for the `autocomplete` class. Also, remove the absolute positioning from the button. This should achieve what you want, but you may have to make some adjustments to the width of the search bar (i.e. `width: 100%`). I edited my original answer to match the solution to your original problem.